# Unable to use $npm_package_version when deploying to Netflify

Tags: reactjs, build, environment-variables, create-react-app, netlify

I have a create-react-app (CRA) deployed to Netlify and I copied over my `.env` file contents over to Netlify's environment variables build settings. I added `REACT_APP_VERSION` as the key with `$npm_package_version` as the value.

But when the app got deployed, this particular environment variable is being shown as a literal string. It doesn't get evaluated to `0.1.0` as what is defined on my `package.json` file. All my other environment variables work just fine because they are string literals. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by [injecting environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#inject-environment-variable-values) using [local build plugins](https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/build-plugins/create-plugins/).

Here's my file structure:

```
> project
  > plugins
    > netlify
      > env
        - index.js
        - manifest.yml
        - package.json ---> only for the plugin (to define as a module)
  ...
  - netlify.toml
  - package.json       ---> where I need to grab values from
  ...
```

And these are the contents of the files:

### index.js

```js
export const onPreBuild = function ({ netlifyConfig, packageJson }) {
    netlifyConfig.build.environment.REACT_APP_NAME = packageJson.name;
    netlifyConfig.build.environment.REACT_APP_VERSION = packageJson.version;
};
```

### manifest.yml

```yaml
name: netlify-env
```

### package.json (inside of plugins/netlify/env directory)

```json
{
    "name": "netlify-env",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "module"
}
```

### netlify.toml

```ini
[[plugins]]
package = "/plugins/netlify/env"
```